# How- A cell value auto copy and paste in B cell at once and whenever the value change of A cell, the value of A added in B cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I want to make an auto calculator cell that means how many times, I am using that particular cell for value, it should be regularly calculated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the data entered in cell A1 to be saved in B1, and each time A1 re-enters one data will automatically add to the original data.

You can use iterative calculations in Excel:

[image]

Use the following formula in B1:

```
=B1+A1
```

Here's the effect:

[image]